# Select Mask Content (Intersection rather than Union) in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, mask

When creating a mask, the resulting cut-out will have the selection size of the object which has parts "cut off" via the mask.

[image: mask selection failure demonstration]

This makes sense for scaling but it is cumbersome for moving and snapping.

The only solution I see now is duplicating the mask region shape and selecting both the mask result and the mask region shape duplicate, to position them. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless Inkscape changes its masking behavior, the bounding box of the masked object will still be the same as the bounding box of the unmasked object.

However, since your mask is pure white, the result of your example can also be done by just clipping, and the clipped bounding box will be the same size as your clipping object.

If your mask contains transparency or non-pure white areas so only portions of the bottom object show through, and you want the result to be the size of your masking object, you can first duplicate the masking object before masking and then clipping the masked object. Or you can copy the masking object to the clipboard, do the mask, paste the copied object in place (Ctrl+Alt+V in Windows) and clip the masked object.[image]